# Inserting data from an arraylist into a ListView throws attempt to invoke virtual error

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I have an activity which has a `ListView` on it ive been trying to populate the list view with data from a String `ArrayList` this is the activity code

```
package com.example.arun.db;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class List_view extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ArrayList<String> throwlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            ListView Trainlist;
            Trainlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.station_list);
            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Station11.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
            try{
                Cursor data_fetch = db.rawQuery("Select Station_name From Station", null);

                String[] station_array = new String[data_fetch.getCount()];
                int i= 0;
                while (data_fetch.moveToNext()) {
                    String name = data_fetch.getString(data_fetch.getColumnIndex("Station_name"));
                    station_array[i] = name;
                    Log.d("STATION_GET","Retrieved station " + station_array[i]);
                    //Toast.makeText(List_view.this, "Retrieved station " + station_array[i] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    throwlist.add(name);
                    i++;

                }
                data_fetch.close();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(List_view.this, "An Error occured Retrieving your data" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            try {

                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, throwlist);
                Trainlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Error in listview ",e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(List_view.this, "Listview Error" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ive identified That the Section 
`

```
try {

                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, throwlist);
                Trainlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Error in listview ",e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(List_view.this, "Listview Error" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }`
```

throws the error

```
10-28 18:03:42.004 11549-11549/com.example.arun.db D/Error in listview: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

upon Further Investigation of this error i knew that this error could be caused by the list view not being declared in the xml file for the particular activity as told in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882414/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-widget-listview-setadapterandroi)

But the ListView is clearly defined in the xml
heres the xml code:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/station_list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Any Ideas As to Why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set  first `setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);` than do controll binding like below code

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
            ArrayList<String> throwlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            ListView Trainlist;
            Trainlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.station_list);
            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Station11.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

            // other code
           }
```

Comment: this fixed the error but the list view is no where to be seen